# Ignore NA values when computing Standard Deviation in R

Tags: r, na

I am using the function of Standard Deviation sd() in R. My question is how to ignore the NA value in the given dataset,
Example of usage :

```
x <- c(0.23,0.26,0.77,0.44,0.35,NA)
sd(x)
```

it returns NA, is there a way to ignore the NA values.

Comment: You probably mean `sd`, not `std`. It has an `na.rm` argument that defaults to false; set it to true to remove `NA` values. Look at `?sd`

Comment: I used the previous response std(l[!is.na(l)]), but it was deleted

Comment: Then where does `std` come from? We can't test out a function if we don't have it

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. There is no `std` function in R packages that are loaded by default at startup. @Amine ... you are asked to include `library` calls to load packages needed. @Hack-R. The OP specifically said it was not `sd` that was being used. You should not put in what you _think_ is correct.

Comment: @Hack-R: your edit was well-intentioned, but I think inadvisable. It's not clear whether the OP really meant `std()` but forgot to specify a package (there is one, e.g., in the `pracma` package: [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/std)), or whether they mistyped `sd()`.  Assuming the latter could potentially muddy the waters (e.g. if they say "I included the `na.rm` flag, but it didn't work" ...)

Comment: (@42-: didn't mean to duplicate your comment, I overlooked it before I wrote mine.)

Comment: FWIW a variant of @Hack-R's answer would work: `all.equal(pracma::std(l[!is.na(l)]),sd(l,na.rm=TRUE))` is TRUE. But I do agree that using the base-R function with the appropriate `na.rm` value is better

Comment: ohh sorry I forget to put this macro, std <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `na.rm=TRUE` when calling `sd()`:

```
R> l <- c(0.23,0.26,0.77,0.44,0.35,NA)
R> sd(l)
[1] NA
R> sd(l, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 0.217371
R>
```